# "Failed to instantiate module jobApp due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] "

Tags: angularjs

I have a .js file with this line:

```
var module = angular.module('jobApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.autoResize', 'ui.grid.resizeColumns'])
```

The module 'jobApp' is not loading.  In a ascx file, I've referenced it like this:

```
    <div ng-app="jobApp" id="job">
    <div>
        <div ng-controller="jobCtrl" ng-init="onLoad('entity')">
        .
        .
</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

When I use the dev tools in IE, I see an error 'SCRIPT5022'. After clicking on the link I see the error in more detail:

"Failed to instantiate module jobApp due to:
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.10/$injector/modulerr?p0=..."

I've tried including 'ng_route' module while including a reference to angular-route, as suggested by SO but jobApp is still not loading.  Why is this not loading?

Comment: Normally that error contains the name of the missing item? Would be useful if you could post the definition on jobCtrl. In fact looking at your module it doesn't include your jobCtrl?

Comment: Yes you're right.  The link in the error points to: "Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to:
{1}" .  So it's not loading my bootstrap file but I don't know why.  How do I find out what {1} refers to?

Answer (score 3):

I got this error so many times.Sometimes this error show because your angular.js file is not included properly . check your cdn of angular.js load properly. and then try to run program

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the ui-bootstrap file wasn't being referenced. All I needed to do was add </script> in my ascx file.  Apologies to Dhara and Dale for not posting a better question.  I should have been more clear as to what the problem was.